# What does moment(testDate, "x") do?

Tags: momentjs

I have the following piece of code before me:

```js
var testDate = 1481103000000;
var enterTime = moment(testDate, "x");
console.log(enterTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

The variable **enterTime** results in a momentjs object with an additional _f property set to "x" and a _pf property of type object (see the console log) compared to a normal **moment(testDate)** object.

I couldn't find information on the _f or _pf properties anywhere.

Can anyone tell me what the "x" stands for and for what reason it is being used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `moment(testDate, "x");` you are creating a moment object using [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) function specifying `x` as format (Unix ms timestamp).

When you do `moment(testDate)`, you are creating a moment object using [`moment(Number);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

All moment properties starting with `_` are for internal use, `_f` stands for *format*, while `_pf` stand for *Parsing Flags*.

You can have a look to moment code to get more details about [`_f`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.17.1/moment.js#L2478) and [`_pf`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.17.1/moment.js#L104).

Answer (score 1):

`x` denotes **Unix ms timestamp**

> Please note that this parameter is case-sensitive:
>
> ```
> X Output: 1410715640.579  Unix timestamp
> x Output: 1410715640579   Unix ms timestamp
> ```

Refer [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for all the options.